# Postgres: hierarchical one to many jsonb aggregation

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, group-by

I have a one-to-many relation between parent and child tables as follows:

**Child table:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| table_id | parent_id | page_index | other_column |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| t1       | p1        |          1 | foo          |
| t1       | p1        |          2 | bar          |
| t2       | p2        |          1 | baz          |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I want to get the final result as follows, i.e. group by parent_id and group by page_index:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| parent_id |                   pages                    |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| p1        | [{other_column: foo}, {other_column: bar}] |
| p2        | [{other_column: baz}]                      |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT parent_table.parent_id, jsonb_agg(child_table.*) as pages
FROM parent_table 
JOIN child_table ON child_table.parent_id = parent_table.parent_id
group by parent_table.parent_id, child_table.page_index
```

But I got the result containing three rows like:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
| parent_id |         pages         |
+-----------+-----------------------+
| p1        | [{other_column: foo}] |
| p1        | [{other_column: bar}] |
| p2        | [{other_column: baz}] |
+-----------+-----------------------+
```

So I did another aggregation on top of that using a subquery and grouping by parent_id again as follows:

```
select sub_q.parent_id, jsonb_agg(sub_q.pages) as pages
from (
SELECT parent_table.parent_id, jsonb_agg(child_table.*) as pages
FROM parent_table 
JOIN child_table ON child_table.parent_id = parent_table.parent_id
group by parent_table.parent_id, child_table.page_index
) as sub_q
```

group by sub_q.parent_id

but I ended up with

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
| parent_id |                     pages                      |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
| p1        | [[{other_column: foo}], [{other_column: bar}]] |
| p2        | [{other_column: baz}]                          |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

how do I get the above desired result with each row having a one-dimensional array using the most optimal query?

Would be great if the answer has a db fiddle!

Comment: Note that your queries relate to a `parent_table`, while your sample data only show `child_table`.

Comment: I wanted to keep the parent table concise assuming that it only has parent_id, but Im happy to add parent table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this. As far as shown in your sample data, you can get the information you want directly from the child table with simple aggregation:

```
select
    parent_id
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('other_column', other_column) order by page_index) pages
from child_table
group by parent_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37b94265be293a3da30fb5422ac5d94a)**:

```
parent_id | pages                                             
:-------- | :-------------------------------------------------
p1        | [{"other_column": "foo"}, {"other_column": "bar"}]
p2        | [{"other_column": "baz"}]
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was overcomplicating. I guess I just needed a fresh set of eyes from you, tysm!